# Activating tabs in a tab panel without accessing it extjs4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I created a tabpanel that has in it two tabs panel_A and panel_B. When the tabpanel opened, only A is active, and B is not, unless you access it. How can i make both tabs active without having to access each item to get it active. Any help please?

```
tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    id: 'tabpanel',
        region: 'center',
        activeTab: 0,
        border:false,
        split:true,
        autoScroll: true,
        tbar: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            deferredRender : false, 
            handler:function(){
                save();
            }   

        }],
        items: [
                {   
                    id:"panel_A",
                    html: "<iframe src= '"+A_url +"' width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_A' name='frm_A' frameborder=0 />",        
                },{
                    id:"panel_B",
                    html: "<iframe src='"+B_url+"'  width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_B' name='frm_B' frameborder=0 />",

                }
                ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
```

Comment: Now sure what exactly you want. How do we know wich tab exaclty we have to activate?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to activate all tabs in your panel **one by one** (idk why you want to do this) you can do something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tabPanel.items.items.length; ++i) {
    tabPanel.setActiveTab(i);
}
```

If if you want to active all tabs (both in your example) **at the same time** I think its not possible.

If you want to activate certain tabs by what criterion we can choose this tabs?

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15lg), update it if you want to clarify your problem.